# Set up button to be reactive after successful Axios request

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button that changes based on method return value:

```
<tr v-for="team in teams" v-bind:key="team.name">
  <td>{{team.name}}</td>
  <div v-show="!teamJoinedSeason(team)">
    <button v-on:click="joinSeason(team.id)">Join Season</button>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <button v-on:click="disjoinSeason(team.id)">Remove from Season</button>
  </div>
</tr>
```

#### teamJoinedSeason(team) function:

```
methods: {
  teamJoinedSeason (team) {
    var user = this.users.find(function (element) {
      return element.id == team.user_id
    })
    return user.joined_applicable_season
  }
}
```

Axios request:

```
joinSeason: function (teamId) {
  const params = {
    team_id: teamId,
    season_id: this.applicable_season.id
  }

  axios.post(process.env.ROOT_API + '/join_season', params, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') }
  }).then(response => {}).catch(error => {})
}
```

#### Data:

```
props: [
    'applicable_season_present',
    'applicable_season',
    'users',
    'teams'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'Team Name', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Team Score', value: 'score' }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This is a child component by the way.

After this request is successful the button does not change. I would like it to be reactive and change the text `remove from season` without have to refresh the entire page. Does anyone know how I can make something like this reactive with Vue.js?

Comment: can you include the data/variables as well please?

Comment: `joinSeason` does nothing but send a `POST` request. It looks like the response handler should set `this.users`.

Comment: `v-else` doesn't work with `v-show`.  you need to use `v-if`, multiple `v-shows` or a different way.

Comment: What do the `team` and `user` arrays look like? How are they altered after making the POST request?